# Inserting data into SQLite database fails with sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: sqlite, python-3.6

I have looked through quite a lot of the ones raised on this site and unless I am being dense ( Which who knows), I don't think they quite replicate my issue.

First let me start with some Code snippets

table

```
         CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS moves(
               ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
               name char(20),
               type char(10),
               category char(10),
               desc char(200),
               share char(3),
               priority char(5),
               damage_dice char(5),
               cool_down char(8),
               accuracy char(100),
               effect char(200),
               move_target char(50),
               makes_contact char(3),
               contest_cat char(10)
         )''')
```

The insert function

```
def insert_moves(move):
    c = dbConn.cursor()
    statement = '''insert into moves values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'''
    try:
        c.execute(statement,(move[0], str(move[1]), str(move[2]), str(move[3]), str(move[4]),
         str(move[5]), str(move[6]), str(move[7]), str(move[8]), str(move[9]), str(move[10]),
         str(move[11]), str(move[12]), str(move[13]),))
        dbConn.commit()
        return True, ''
    except Exception as e:
        return False, e
```

Now, let me show you the stack trace and as part of that, you will see the printed output of move before its passed into the datebase function.

Now, this is the output

```
[1, 'Attack Order', 'Bug', 'Physical', 'The user calls out its underlings to pummel the target.', 'Yes', '-', '1d6', '1 Turn', '100', 'Attack Order deals damage and has an increased critical hit ratio of 50 percent', 'Targets a single adjacent Pokemon.', 'No', 'Clever']
Ignoring exception in command update_moves:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/pokebot/gsheet.py", line 59, in update_moves
    result, error2 = db.insert_moves(moves)
  File "/projects/pokebot/db.py", line 103, in insert_moves
    c.execute(statement,(move[0], str(move[1]), str(move[2]), str(move[3]), str(move[4]), str(move[5]), str(move[6]), str(move[7]), str(move[8]), str(move[9]), str(move[10]), str(move[11]), str(move[12]), str(move[13]),))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I have tried a few things such as removing random percent signs in case that was the issue, or changing Pokémon to Pokemon. But I don't see what the issue is. A lot of the others were all about people sending in things like Lists or objects to insert instead of some string/int object and I don't believe that to be the issue here. Is there anything that stands out?

Comment: What is `move`? Where is it defined?

Comment: `move` is a list with its contents printed out right before the stack trace.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: You can simplify it to: `c.execute(statement,move)`

Comment: @forpas  Yeah, I was trying to get it right...but now that I found my issue, that definitely is much cleaner. I keep forgetting about that but its such an elegant way to handle this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So...this was definitely my fault. And if I had posted the function that called the insert, I would have seen it. I guess its just a friday afternoon and my brain is tired.

```
    print(move)
    result, error2 = db.insert_moves(move)
```

this was written as

```
    print(move)
    result, error2 = db.insert_moves(moves)
```

Where moves is iterated over so that I can do some work on it. Honestly, this was my fault completely. Oh well, I think the lesson is....on the insert function, if you are getting this error, check the type of the value passed. Which honestly, I should have done by now..but I'll just chalk it up to Friday afternoon.